# Slow UI update, add Spinner

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, segue

I've created an iPad App which internally load a large amount of media, which can freeze the UI for a few seconds (especially on older iPads).  I'm exploring async and adding a spinner, but it I haven't been able to identify the right spot for spinner to start prior to new ViewController opening.  Any help is appreaciated.

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

[activityIndicatorObject startAnimating];

dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("downloader", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{

    understandingViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.itemNumber = num1;
    destViewController.selectedItem = num1;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [activityIndicatorObject stopAnimating];
    });

});
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Use `ViewDidLoad` in the destinationViewController to add activityIndicator and startAnimating.

and in the ViewDidLoad , load your data in a background thread

so something like this

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
    // add activity indicator
    // start animating

      dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        // Perform non main thread operation
        // load data
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // perform main thread operation
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: But which view would be in background when spinner appears?

Comment: the destination view controller view will be visible

Comment: Only issue is currently I'm seeing that freeze of UI on current ViewController, not destination.

Comment: use breakpoints in your destinationVC viewDiDLoad and in prepareForSegue and step one line at a time to find out where exactly most of the time is taken

Comment: if you are free , head over to SO Chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ faster help

Comment: I see where it's taking time, as soon as I click a button to segue, there is a freeze before the new view appears.

Answer (score 0):

You sound confused. View controllers are not "in the background". CODE runs in the background. You should not be doing async calls in prepareForSegue.

I would suggest skipping calls to dispatch_async() entirely. Instead, look at using NSURLConnection's `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` method. That will let you submit a connection request (pass in the main queue for the the queue parameter) and a block of code that you want to execute once the connection is complete. The system handles doing the download asynchronously and notifies you when it's done.

Comment: I'm not connecting to an URL, should this still be used?

Comment: So what ARE you doing then?

Comment: I have a large amount of images loading in destination

Comment: Loading from local storage? As long as the code you're using to load them is thread-safe, you can use the dispatch_async code @Kabira  posted.